# could not convert 'digitalWrite(8u, 1u)' from 'void' to 'bool'

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-nano, led, drone

I am trying to make some LED lights to turn on when i flick a switch on my RC crontroller. I will connect the signal wire from RC controller to pin 8. The plan is: if i flick the swich, the LED's (pin 12,11,10,9) will turn on, and if i don't flick the swich the LED's wont turn on. This is a Arduino nano what will be connected on a drone.I found another question [HERE](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/17006/arduino-ide-says-fcould-not-convert-pinmodebuttonsinti-0u-from-void), but there was no real answers.
 I get a error that say:

> exit status 1
>   could not convert 'digitalWrite(8u, 1u)' from 'void' to 'bool'

How can i fix this? Should i write the code another way?

Arduino Code:

```
    void setup() {

  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8, INPUT);



}


void loop() {

  if (digitalWrite(8, HIGH));
    digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(11, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(9, HIGH); 
  else 
    digitalWrite(12, LOW);
    digitalWrite(11, LOW);
    digitalWrite(10, LOW);
    digitalWrite(9, LOW);

  digitalWrite(4,HIGH);
  delay(1500);
  digitalWrite(4,LOW);
}
```

Comment: why has this question upvotes?

Comment: Because it’s a clear, answerable question with an error message and (relatively) minimal reproduction @Juraj

Comment: upvote is for "usefull". and I agree with the text in bubble over the downvote button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `digitalRead(8)` instead of `digitalWrite(8, HIGH)`. Your sketch is also missing some curly brackets.

```
void setup(){
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8, INPUT);
}

void loop(){
  if(digitalRead(8) == HIGH){
    digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(11, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
  } 
  else{
    digitalWrite(12, LOW);
    digitalWrite(11, LOW);
    digitalWrite(10, LOW);
    digitalWrite(9, LOW);
  }
  digitalWrite(4,HIGH);
  delay(1500);
  digitalWrite(4,LOW);
}
```

The use of `delay()` will block the sketch from doing anything else, and should be replaced with a `millis()` timer. Have a look at the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example in the IDE.

Comment: Can't i just make another `void loop()` and have the blinking there? Then it won't interfere with the if statement.

Comment: You can only have 1 `void loop()`. There are several libraries available that are easier to use than writing your own code, such as https://www.avdweb.nl/arduino/timing/virtualdelay. This library lets you use a similar syntax as the `delay()` function, and is non blocking.

Answer (score 1):

This line of code is the source of your problem.

> ```
> void loop() {
>
>   if (digitalWrite(8, HIGH));
> ```

If expressions expect a boolean (true/false), but if you check [the documentation for `digitalWrite()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/digital-io/digitalwrite/), you’ll see it returns “Nothing” (i.e. `void`).

You need to use [`digitalRead()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/digital-io/digitalread/) to check the current state of the pin.